# Swift - List Data from Firebase in Table View

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, runtime-error

I want to table list data from firebase.

[This is my activity table from Firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gmvS.png)

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseAnalytics
import FirebaseFirestore


class activitys{

var act_name: String?
var act_owner: String?

init(act_name: String?, act_owner: String?) {
   self.act_name = act_name
   self.act_owner = act_owner
   }
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var actTableView: UITableView!

var activityList = [activitys]()

var ref : DatabaseReference!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return activityList.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell


        let test = activityList[indexPath.row]
        cell.act_name?.text = test.act_name
        cell.act_owner?.text = test.act_owner

        return cell

        }



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ref = Database.database().reference()

    actTableView.dataSource = self
    actTableView.delegate = self
    fetchActivityList()


}


func fetchActivityList(){

    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("Activity").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
                let results = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
                let name = results?["act_name"]
                let owner = results?["act_owner"]
                let myAct = activitys(act_name: name as! String?, act_owner: owner as! String?)
                self.activityList.append(myAct)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.actTableView!.reloadData()
                }
        })
}


}
```

This project will crash when run.

error message: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

[And the error message like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUTCC.png)

I make sure all the outlet is connected.
I can give you the source code if you know how to solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: this isn't about firebase, check if your tableView binded with your storyboard view.

Comment: I checked the view controller, table view, the label is binded with my storyboard view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)I guess you have just declared the tableView but not wired to the story board.

2)Make sure class is a UIViewController and not a UITableViewController, I think your connections are not wired up correctly.

3)Remove This Outlets

[image: Remove This Outlets]

4) HomeViewController.swift

```
//
//  HomeViewController.swift
//  EnJoin
//
//  Created by 陳曉聰 on 6/1/2020.
//  Copyright © 2020 Chan Hiu Chung. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
//import Firebase
//import FirebaseAuth
//import FirebaseStorage
//import FirebaseDatabase
//import FirebaseAnalytics
//import FirebaseFirestore


class activitys{

    var act_name: String?
    var act_owner: String?

    init(act_name: String?, act_owner: String?) {
        self.act_name = act_name
        self.act_owner = act_owner
    }
}


class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{


    @IBOutlet weak var actTableView: UITableView!



//    var activityList = [activitys]()
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

    //    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell

        cell.act_name.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //        ref = Database.database().reference()


        actTableView.delegate = self
        actTableView.dataSource = self

        //        fetchActivityList()

    }



    //    func fetchActivityList(){
    //
    //        ref = Database.database().reference()
    //        ref.child("Activity").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
    //                    let results = snapshot.value as? [String : AnyObject]
    //                    if let name = results?["act_name"] as? String,let owner = results?["act_owner"] as? String{
    //                      let myAct = activitys(act_name: name, act_owner: owner)
    //                        self.activityList.append(myAct)
    //                    }
    //                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    //                        self.actTableView!.reloadData()
    //                    }
    //            })
    //    }


}
```

Comment: my view controller class: class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

Comment: Thank you for your help. I removed that 2 Outlets. But still runtime error. is that work in your version?

Comment: yes, just copy your HomeViewController.swift,HomeTableViewCell.swift, Home Screen from storyboard  and also edit your HomeViewController.swift.i am putting that File in step 4

Comment: How to get the text from the selected row? I want to storge the selected text in struct.

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
       let selectedText = items[indexPath.row]
    }

Comment:  Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in line `no.82`

> An optional value can be unwrapped safely or forcibly. If you
>   force-unwrap an optional, and it didn't have a value, your program
>   will crash with the above message.

```
let myAct = activitys(act_name: name as! String?, act_owner: owner as! String?)
```

Check if the value of `name` and `owner` is available before you unwrap it.

```
if let name = results?["act_name"] a? String,let owner = results?["act_owner"] 
{
  let myAct = activitys(act_name: name, act_owner: owner)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I followed your code but the error is still here and the same.